# Can't expose monotone convex interpolation in python quantlib

Tags: quantlib, quantlib-swig

Using quantlib 1.9 and downloaded it as a precompiled binary as made available on  prof christoph goehlke's website.

I want to use monotone convex interpolation for bootstrapping a curve from a set of instruments.

But I am unable to see the function under the installation. Therefore using piecewise flat forwards.

Any suggestions on making monotone convex interpolation work?? Python 2.7 is the interpreter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ templates must be instantiated at compile time, interpolations can't be enabled on a precompiled binary when missing.  To export them, you'll have to modify the SWIG interfaces, regenerate the wrappers and recompile the module.

The modifications should be in couple of places. In `interpolations.i`, you'll have to export the `ConvexMonotone` class; you can mimic what's done, e.g., for the `Cubic` class (unfortunately, you'll have to live with the default `quadraticity`, `monotonicity` and `forcePositive` parameters). In `piecewiseyieldcurve.i`, instead, you'll have to add the instantiation you want with an additional call to the `export_piecewise_curve` macro.

If that proves too difficult, you can ask for help on the QuantLib mailing list at `quantlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net`.